# classNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a problem when manipulating OWL ontology with tomcat7 and java servlet. It works with normal java class but not with tomcat. I have the following error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec

I tried copying jena jars from jena/lib to web-inf/lib but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Add jar file containing `com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec` class in your project's build path.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried copying jena jars from jena/lib to web-inf/lib but still not working

You must MOVE the jars to `web-inf/lib`

---

Check that the file (.jar) is really in the "deployed" Tomcat directory.
If not, press F5 (refesh) in the project Explorer and my "clean" the Tomcat in Eclipse. (Sometimes the refresh does not work 100% correct).